# Sum of array elements in Bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have to calculate the total num of positive and  (negative+null or empty values) from the table basically 2 values . I have the below query to list the negative and null and positive values .. but i want the entire count . please assist.

```
SELECT
ARRAY(
SELECT count(value),
FROM UNNEST(event_data_results) where REGEXP_CONTAINS(name, r'data.result.result') and ((REGEXP_CONTAINS(value, r'^-?\d+$') and SAFE_CAST(value AS INT64) <= 0 ))) AS negative_attributes,
ARRAY(
SELECT count(value) as neg_val,
FROM UNNEST(event_data_results) where  value = 'null' or value='' ) AS null_attributes,
ARRAY(
SELECT count(value),
FROM UNNEST(event_data_results) where REGEXP_CONTAINS(name, r'data.result.result') and (REGEXP_CONTAINS(value, r'^-?\d+$') and SAFE_CAST(value AS INT64) > 0 )) AS positive_attributes
FROM `table` where EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(event_keys) as keys , UNNEST(event_data_results) as results WHERE keys.value = "attribute")
```

[image]

event_keys,event_data_results , data_metrics all are repeatable struct

result should be postive : 4 negative+null :4

Comment: example of input data and expected result will help

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant the input table look like above so the result should be how many positive attribute are there in total and how many negative attributes+null or empty attributes are there

Comment: total in table? or per row?

Comment: total in table only matching the condition as ( "key.value as attribute ) @MikhailBerlyant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  COUNTIF(result.value > 0) positive_attributes,
  COUNTIF(result.value < 0) negative_attributes,
  COUNTIF(IFNULL(result.value, 0) = 0) null_or_zero_attributes
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(event_data_results) AS result   
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM UNNEST(event_keys) AS key
  WHERE key.value = "attribute"
)
```

you can add here whatever conditions you need

Also, if `result.value` is a string - you can use `SAFE_CAST(result.value AS INT64)` as you already do so i was not focusing on this aspect of your case

Comment: the count and selected rows count is changing when we add condition in another record , for example i need to add the condition for type = attribute in where if i add SELECT
  COUNTIF(result.value > 0) positive_attributes,
  COUNTIF(result.value < 0) negative_attributes,
  COUNTIF(IFNULL(result.value, 0) = 0) null_or_zero_attributes
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(event_data_results) AS result  ,UNNEST(event_keys)  as keys where keys.value="attribute" its giving wrong no of rows and counts

Comment: what is the type of `event_keys` field? is it array(`repeated record`) or simple struct(`nullable record`)?

Comment: also, update your data sample to support that issue you just mentioned in your comment, so we can reproduce and fix it

Comment: anyway, see updated answer  - I added WHERE clause - I thought it is obvious as it was already in your initial query

Comment: only null  total value is coming wrong .. apart from that positive and negative values are correct

Comment: great! so, I hope you will be able to complete this by yourself. meantime consider voting up the answer (assuming it really helped) and accept it

Comment: Btw, instead of `FROM \`project.dataset.table\`, UNNEST(event_data_results) AS result `, try `FROM \`project.dataset.table\` LEFT JOIN UNNEST(event_data_results) AS result `. This should prevent from loosing NULL entries - just try as an option

Comment: both left join also gives same result. I think the null condition is not working as expected . If result.value is null  and this field is a string .. what i have here is COUNTIF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(result.name, r'data.result.result') and (IFNULL(SAFE_CAST(result.value AS INT64), 0) = 0)) null_or_zero_attributes  or i tries removing the safe_cast also

Comment: If you have issue with regexp - i suggest you to post new question as it has nothing really to do with issue we just resolved.

Comment: sure i think this resolves the null values ..COUNTIF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(result.name, r'data.result.result') and (value = 'null' or value='' )).. Thank you

Comment: nice. glad you made it :o)